# Why Azure blob is not traceable or recognizable even though it exists?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-blob-storage

My code is working fine with other container-A and A-1blob in it. but its not working for rest of the containers and its blobs.
I am writing a code to extract perticular column from the json file and converting file to csv in my local disk.
I don't know why its not recognizing other container and blob. they all are json files only and size of the file is not more than 16 mb.

```
import csv
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import json

# Azure Blob storage connection string
    connection_string = 'my_connection_string'

    # Blob container and file information
    container_name = 'my_container_name'
    blob_name = 'My_jsonfile.json'

    # Create BlobServiceClient instance
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

    # Get BlobClient for the JSON file
    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=blob_name)

    # Download and load the JSON data
    blob_data = blob_client.download_blob().content_as_text()
    json_data = json.loads(blob_data)`your text`

    # Define the local CSV file path
    csv_file_path = 'local_path'

    # Define the fieldnames for the CSV file
    fieldnames = ['id', 'type', 'actor/login', 'payload/issue/labels/0/name', 'payload/issue/body', 'payload/issue/title',]
    # Open the local CSV file in write mode
    with open(csv_file_path, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()

    
    # Write the data rows
    for event in json_data:
        try:
            id = event['id']
            type = event['type']
            actor = event['actor']['login']
            name = event['payload']['issue']['labels'][0]['name']
            body = event['payload']['issue']['body']
            title = event['payload']['issue']['title']

            writer.writerow({'id': id, 'type': type, 'actor/login': actor,     'payload/issue/labels/0/name': name, 'payload/issue/body': body, 'payload/issue/title': title})
        except (KeyError, IndexError):
            # Handle missing keys or empty lists gracefully
            pass

       
            print(' ')
            print()  # Add an empty line for separation

print('CSV file created successfully! File path:', csv_file_path)
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Please edit your question and include those details.

Answer (score 0):

***I made some changes with your code and got the json blob data from three containers in my storage account to CSV file.***

I have created threee containers with three json blobs in my storage account at Azure portal.

Below is the **json blob** data in the **first container** in my **storage account** in **Azure portal**.

[image]

Here is the **json blob** data in the **second container** in my **storage account** in **Azure portal**.

[image]

And this is the **json blob** data in the **third container** in my **storage account** in **Azure portal**.

[image]

**Code:**

I tried the below code to get the json blob data of three containers in my storage account to CSV file.

```py
import csv
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import json

connection_string = '<connec-string>'
fieldnames = ['id', 'type', 'actor/login', 'payload/issue/labels/0/name', 'payload/issue/body', 'payload/issue/title']
csv_file_path = '<path-to-csvFile>'

def extract_column_from_json(blob_data):
    json_data = json.loads(blob_data)
    rows = []

    for event in json_data:
        try:
            id = event['id']
            type = event['type']
            actor = event['actor']['login']
            name = event['payload']['issue']['labels'][0]['name']
            body = event['payload']['issue']['body']
            title = event['payload']['issue']['title']

            row = {'id': id, 'type': type, 'actor/login': actor,
                   'payload/issue/labels/0/name': name, 'payload/issue/body': body, 'payload/issue/title': title}
            rows.append(row)
        except (KeyError, IndexError):
            pass
    return rows

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
containers = ['<first-container>', '<second-container>', '<third-container>'] 
blob_names = ['<firstcontainer-jsonblob>', '<secondcontainer-jsonblob>', '<thirdcontainer-jsonblob>']

for container_name, blob_name in zip(containers, blob_names):
    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=blob_name)

    try:
        blob_data = blob_client.download_blob().content_as_text()
        rows = extract_column_from_json(blob_data)
        with open(csv_file_path, 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            writer.writerows(rows)

        print(f'Successfully extracted column from JSON in container: {container_name}')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error extracting column from JSON in container: {container_name}')
        print(f'Error message: {str(e)}')

print('CSV file created successfully! File path:', csv_file_path)
```

**Output:**

It runs successfully and copied the three json blobs data to CSV file.

[image]

***Successfully copied the above three json blob data to CSV file as below,***

[image]